# Static import overloaded method

Tags: java, android, import, static, overloading

I have my DateUtils.java file which has date related utility methods. I have overloaded method `setDate()` like below :

```
// Overloaded method #1
public static void setDate(Date date) { }

// Overloaded method #2
public static void setDate(long timestamp) { }
```

I am using only one of above method in my other class files. For example, `setDate(Date date)` method.
When I tried to static import this method, it imported like :

```
import static com.example.app.DateUtils.setDate;
```

This statement imports both overloaded method in my implementation where as I am only using one overloaded method, not both.

Is there any way to **static import** overloaded method selectively? I mean, can I statically import only the method for which I am interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to static import overloaded method selectively? I mean, can I statically import only the method for which I am interested in?

No, you can't. Remember that static import (import in general) is merely a mechanism for defining a shorthand version of referring to things. All that `import java.util.Map;` does is let you use `Map` where otherwise you would have had to type `java.util.Map`. It's the same for a static import, it's purely a means of getting a shorthand name for (in your case) `com.example.all.DateUtils.setDate`.

If you *could* import just one overload and not the other, all it would do is make this not match a valid signature:

```
setDate(1234L);
```

...which isn't all that useful.

If you want to make using the `long` overload separate from using the `Date` overload, you'll have to split them into separate, non-overloaded methods.